# Console working, server not

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have two models, named User and Email. User has many Email, and Email belongs to User. I open up my console and I have this:

```
> user = User.find(3)
> user.email[1].confirmed?
false
```

Everything works as expected in my console, but on the server, email[1] is nil:NilClass, and I have checked its presence and user does exist. What's going on here....?

Something similar suggests it's a matter of method ( forgetting the word [scope?] ) public or private thing... eh But I don't know if it is that? What could this be?

Comment: can you post your error stacktrace

Comment: Method not found "confirmed?" in nil:NilClass

Comment: From the error message `email[1]` is `nil`

Comment: Same machine? Same environment (development, production, ...?) Not sandboxing?

Comment: Are You sure that user with id = 3 has minimum two emails? Run this: User.find(3).email.size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to the following:

```
user.email[1].try(:confirmed?)
```

It is simply equivalent of checking presence and calling a method if there's an object.

Comment: I think the OP is saying that the user is expected to exist, but doesn't, in one of the environments.

Comment: I think thats working, because it passes as I expected with original code, but why?

Comment: @DaveNewton No that not

Comment: @user3180221 Then you need to describe the problem better. User.find(3) is User.find(3). If the user exists on the server, but not on the console, and nothing else is different, then something is wrong.